# The uiautomatorviewer is causing my samsung galaxy on7 Pro to switch off

Tags: android, mobile, appium, uiautomatorviewer

I am facing an issue with UI automatorviewer,I have a samsung galaxy on7 pro device with OS 6.1.0 , currently I am using it for appium automation purpose, what happens is when ever the test is done executed and i stop the appium server and  the uiautomatorviewer through commmand prompt,my samsung device connected to the laptop by USB also gets switched off each time. Not sure whats happening , why uiautomatorviewer is triggering shutting down of my device, can any body help me in this?

Answer (score 0):

I hope your real device is not shutting down when your are running the script and it happens only when you are trying to find the UI elements objects using UiAutomatorViewer.

Why do you need a Real Device with UiAutomatorViewer to identify the UI elements? You can use any emulator right? there will remain same UI elements even if you install your app(apk) into emulator or real device with UIAutomatorViewer.